# I am getting an Error in format default function when trying to use it with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

**This is my Code:**

```
yearly.ts<- data.frame (Years = as.Date(c('01/01/1985','01/01/1986','01/01/1987','01/01/1988','01/01/1989'),"%d/%m/%Y"),SUMS = c(sum(Appliance.df$Shipments[which(format(Appliance.df$Quarter, "%y")=="85")]),sum(Appliance.df$Shipments[which(format(Appliance.df$Quarter, "%y")=="86")]),sum(Appliance.df$Shipments[which(format(Appliance.df$Quarter, "%y")=="87")]),sum(Appliance.df$Shipments[which(format(Appliance.df$Quarter, "%y")=="88")]),sum(Appliance.df$Shipments[which(format(Appliance.df$Quarter, "%y")=="89")])))


ggplot(yearly.ts) + 
  geom_line(aes(Years,SUMS,color=SUMS)) + 
  labs(title = "LINE CHART",caption = "(based on data from yearly.ts)", x = "Years", y = "Shipments") + 
  ylim(16400,18500) + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels="%Y",date_breaks  ="1 years")
```

**The error I am getting is:**

```
Error in format.default(structure(as.character(x), names = names(x), dim = dim(x), : invalid 'trim' argument
```

I am trying to replicate the output which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This is not reproducible because `Appliance.df` is not defined.

Comment: Hi Rax9 and welcome to SO!  We are not going to be able to answer your question unless we are able to reproduce the result.  The easiest step here is probably to share with us the data frame `yearly.ts` that you are trying to use for creating your chart.  The way to do that is to type the command `dput(yearly.ts)` into your console.  The output will likely start with something like `structure(...)` - just copy and paste that into your question, formatted as code, please, which can allow others to recreate your data frame exactly as you have it and answer your question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to set `Years` as factor:

```
yearly.ts$Years = as.factor(yearly.ts$Years)
```